# Props returns undefined, but I can see its value in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tiny, but frustrating bug. I have a parent component that passes down a prop to its child:

### Parent:

```
const { door } = this.props || []
...
{this.state.showModal ? <ClusterModal door={door} /> : null}
```

And when I want to access it in my child component:`this.props.door`.

Also the `door` props has a key called `doors` that I want to access. So I tried: `console.log(this.props.door.doors)` and my console gives me:

[image]
Which is great! However React tells me this:

> Cannot read property 'doors' of undefined

Sorry if this is a bad explained question, but I can't figure this out.

Thanks for reading!

#### Edit

Here's the parent:

```
const { door } = this.props
const ifCluster = (
  <div>
    {door.type === 'cluster' ? (
      <div className="door-flex-item-2">
        <a
          className="sub-title-text-container"
          onClick={() => this.toggleModalButton()}
        >
          Hejsan
        </a>
        {this.state.showModal ? this.props.door ? (
          <ClusterModal door={door} />
        ) : null : null}
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
)
```

And here's the child:

```
render() {
  // const { door } = this.props || []

  const customers = this.props.customers || []
  const keyedCustomers = _.keyBy(customers, '_id')

  const deliveries = this.props.deliveries || []
  const keyedDeliveries = _.keyBy(deliveries, '_id')

  console.log(this.props.door)
  const clusterDoors = this.props.door.doors.map((clusterDoor, i) => {
    console.log(clusterDoor)
```

I noticed that the first time I log `this.props.door` I get the data, but the second time it gets `undefined` for some reason.

Comment: We'll probably need some fiddle/codepen to have a clear vision of your problem!

Comment: Value in console is evaluated value. So it could be undefined first and assigned later.

Comment: Have you tried: const { doors } = this.props.door || []?

Comment: As with [your now-deleted last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464711/prop-disappears-after-second-render), please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Read the MCVE link, it contains important information about why this is a useful thing to do, for yourself and for the site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :-)

Answer (score 0):

Store the prop values in state and check the values are same as in your props. Do it in **ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)** method.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition to your component like this

```
(this.props.door) ? <ClusterModal door={door} /> : <Div/>
```

So, it will only render component once it has value within door

**Edit**:

```
{
  (this.state.showModal)
  ? (this.props.door)
    ? <ClusterModal door={door} />
    : null
  : null
}
```

or you can use function as well

```
clusterModel = () => { // change according to requirement
  if (this.state.showModal) {
    if (this.props.door) {
      <ClusterModal door={door} />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would it look if already have a inline if/else? Please see my updated question.

Comment: How would it look if already have a inline if/else? Please see my updated question.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me, but it didn't do the trick :(

Comment: can you please update your code and also add  code where `doors` is used so others can help you

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you will see the error:

> Cannot read property 'doors' of undefined

Is that the `this.props.door.doors` from inside of `ClusterModal` component returns undefined at the `door` property.

And this is the case of `const { door } = this.props || []` setting door to undefined. This happens because the right hand side `this.props || []` evaluates to `[]` and the left side fails to do the object deconstruction because you have an array instead of an object with the `door` key.

A quick fix should be to do:

```
const { door } = this.props || { door: { doors: []} }
```

Then inside of your ClusterModal you will NOT get that error.

Here you have the rules of [object and array destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html).

Please check this because `const { door } = this.props || []` **does not makes sense.**

Comment: I tried your solution, but I either get `undefined` with your first solution, or just an empty object with the second.

Comment: @MartinNordström Updated my response to simplify things. That's the correct way to destructure the object, the [] is wrong, you should update your code, that's the first step to find the bug.